# Using lapply with if to test each element in a list

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply

Suppose I have a list:

```
alist<- list(4,6,8,9)
```

I want test if each list element is greater than 7 and return a list of 1 if its true and 0 if false.

However I must use lapply.

```
lapply(alist,if,>7,1) or lapply(alist,if,cond>7,1)
```

Of course none of these work and I keep getting the following error.

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "lapply(alist, if,"
```

Comment: I know you want to use `lapply` but: `as.numeric(alist > 7)` works nicely.

Comment: Ha ha yip Carl you nailed it. I had gotten I think about 30% of the way to figuring out the assignment when I ran into this. Thought it was a good question though as lapply has ... as an argument and I figured somewhere in there I could finish the if statement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It pains me to answer this because it's very un R to do this.  You could try being more explicit and use brackets as in:

```
lapply(alist, function(x) if (x > 7) {1} else {0})
```

Or the vectorized `ifelse`

```
lapply(alist, function(x) ifelse(x > 7, 1, 0))
```

Or best of all:

```
as.numeric(alist > 7)
```

Comment: +1 same as my answer, but I would make note of ifelse() being a bit unintuitive as this seems to be a new R user. Funny that I say this because the immediate question before this was somene complaining about a closure error with ifelse() lol.

Comment: You are very correct (IMO) about `ifelse`.  I answered and `ifelse` problem last evening as well (when the user should have been using `if(){} else{}`)

Answer (score 3):

Another two:

```
lapply(alist > 7, as.integer)
```

or

```
lapply(alist > 7, ifelse, 1, 0)
```