# R: How do I check if all values of unnamed list of lists are TRUE?

Tags: r, list

my list `ll`

```r
ll <- list(list(c("loss", "acceptor", "118595910-118595911", "Medium", 
"13.196532"), c("gain", "acceptor", "118595911-118595912", "Medium", 
"9.953203")), list(c("loss", "donor", "976214-976215", "Medium", "7.866191")),
list(c("loss", "acceptor", "112145998-112145999","Medium", "8.728467"),
c("gain", "acceptor", "112145999-112146000", "Medium", "2.721802")),
list(c("loss", "acceptor", "55871763-55871764", "Medium", "6.049719"),
c("gain", "acceptor", "55871764-55871765", "Medium", "5.105557")))
```

I want to check if the 5th `numeric` elements (in the list, it is a `character`) are all bigger than `4` which means I only want one logical value returned by list, here in this case would be `TRUE`, `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `TRUE`.

I am aware of the threads found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112316/using-lapply-with-if-to-test-each-element-in-a-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104348/how-to-check-that-element-of-a-list-of-lists-matches-a-condition) however my list is unnamed and I am not sure how do I access each subset of my list. I can unwrap them but this means I would obtain more logical values than the number of lists:

```
matrix(unlist(ll),ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
     [,1]   [,2]       [,3]                  [,4]     [,5]       
[1,] "loss" "acceptor" "118595910-118595911" "Medium" "13.196532"
[2,] "gain" "acceptor" "118595911-118595912" "Medium" "9.953203" 
[3,] "loss" "donor"    "976214-976215"       "Medium" "7.866191" 
[4,] "loss" "acceptor" "112145998-112145999" "Medium" "8.728467" 
[5,] "gain" "acceptor" "112145999-112146000" "Medium" "2.721802" 
[6,] "loss" "acceptor" "55871763-55871764"   "Medium" "6.049719" 
[7,] "gain" "acceptor" "55871764-55871765"   "Medium" "5.105557"
```

I know I should use `any`, `sapply`, `as.numeric` but I really don't know how to put them together...

```r
any( sapply(ll_test,function(x) as.numeric(x[5]) > 4) )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nested `sapply`:

```
sapply(ll,function(x) all(sapply(x,function(y) as.numeric(y[5]) > 4 )))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Basically, you use `sapply` to apply `sapply` to every element of the inner list to every element of the outer list. Confused?

Comment: Thanks for the proposed answer. It was getting too complicated and confusing in my brain but seeing your answer made it all clear !